# pg admin 4 postgresql 11.6 "fatal error application server could not be contacted."

Tags: pgadmin-4

I installed postgresql 11.6 but when I want to open pg admin 4 I take  "fatal error application server could not be contacted". I tried execute as administrator and also delete c/:users/appdata/roaimg/pgadmin file but also not working. How can I open pgadmin 4 on my browser?

Comment: Hello, welcome to the site :) could you add some additional information about your setup? Are you running Postgres and PGAdmin on the same machine? Are you certain the database is running? Have you checked if it is binding to port 5432? How exactly did you install it? did you make any effort to configure the database (ie. modifying the config files), and if you did, what did you change? Are you sure there is no firewall setting blocking the database?

Comment: I installed from postgresql website. I clicked next to all pages. Also I installed PostGIS on stack builder. Before I installed 11.6 I had 11.5. 11.5 version was working but I took same fatal error message. I reseted my computer and install again but I took same message. My port is 5432. I don’t configured anything.